# How to add custom token when doing signup authenctication using firebase in angular?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I need to authenticate through email and password when signing up in my angular app. The required `auth.service.` and `onSubmit` method are as follows. Email and password sign in providers are enabled in firebase authentication section.

**auth.service.ts**

```
  signup(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=[REPLACE_WITH_MY_API_KEY]', {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      returnSecureToken: true
    })
  }
```

**auth.component.ts**

```
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (!form.valid) {
      return;
    }
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;

    if (this.isLoginMode) {
      //....
    } else {
      this.authService.signup(email, password).subscribe(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    form.reset();
  }
```

According to the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) , a token parameter should be passed to this. How to generate it and add it in this signup method?. A 400 error occurs when executing the method in this way.

Comment: what does signup return in the body?

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong url to signup on firebase with email and password
Look at this section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password